# InfluxDB 2.x - how to get minimum _time for all records in measurement?

Tags: flux, influxdb-2

I need to get minimum _time for all records in measurement without grouping by tags. How I can do that using flux?

I don't find some examples of agregation functions for tags or _time field. Only for values.

```
from(bucket: "testbucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "TEST_MEASUREMENT")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "_time")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: min, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "min")
```